# Cocoa WebView with private browsing - WebPreferences not been applied

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview, webkit

I am trying to enable Private Browsing in a Cocoa WebView on a Mac App, however my WebPreferences are not been applied for some reason.  Does anyone have any ideas?  The WebView doesn't end up using Private Browsing.

```
    WebPreferences *firstWebViewWebPreferences = [[WebPreferences init] alloc];
[firstWebViewWebPreferences setPrivateBrowsingEnabled:YES];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:firstWebViewWebPreferences forKey:@"firstWebViewWebPreferencesDefaults"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[firstWebView setPreferencesIdentifier:@"firstWebViewWebPreferencesDefaults"];
```

I also tried:

```
    WebPreferences *firstWebViewWebPreferences = [[WebPreferences init] alloc];
[firstWebViewWebPreferences setPrivateBrowsingEnabled:YES];
[firstWebView setPreferences:firstWebViewWebPreferences];
```

as both appear to match the documentation, but on both occasions my WebView is keeping Cookies and saving history that can be seen by Safari.  Any help about what mistake I am making here is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is with this line :

```
WebPreferences *firstWebViewWebPreferences = [[WebPreferences init] alloc];
```

You are calling the init before the alloc. Replace it with this :

```
WebPreferences *firstWebViewWebPreferences = [[WebPreferences alloc] init];
```

Or try this :

```
WebPreferences *firstWebViewWebPreferences = [WebPreferences standardPreferences];
...
```